# Custom Query Not Paginating

Tags: functions, wp-query, pagination

I have a site that uses a custom query to filter posts:

```
<?php //Search Region table to retrieve array of country names
$regionresult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gallery_regions WHERE region='$region'") or die(mysql_error());
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($regionresult);

// Process search reults and format array contents for WP Query
$country_search_array = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($regionresult)){
    $country_search_array[] = $row['country']; 
        }

//Build WP query
$args = array(
     'posts_per_page' => '48',
     'cat' => '4',
     'meta_query' => array(
         array(
            'key' => 'Country',
            'value' => $country_search_array,
            'compare' => 'IN'
        )
    )
);
$gallery_query = new WP_Query( $args );?>
```

supplemented by a custom function that paginates the results, using the WP Page Numbers plugin (http://www.jenst.se/2008/03/29/wp-page-numbers):

```
function wp_page_numbers_custom( $wp_query, $start = '', $end = '' )
{
    $_backup = array(
        'wp_query' => @ $GLOBALS['wp_query'],
        'max_page' => @ $GLOBALS['max_page'],
           'paged' => @ $GLOBALS['paged'],  
    );

    $GLOBALS['wp_query'] = $wp_query;
    $GLOBALS['max_page'] = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
       $GLOBALS['paged'] = max( $wp_query->get( 'paged' ), 1 );

    wp_page_numbers( $start, $end );

    foreach ( $_backup as $var => $val )
        $GLOBALS[ $var ] = $val;
}

//usage: wp_page_numbers_custom( $gallery_query );
```

While the number of pages returned is accurate, the navigation isn't working. If you click on page 2 of X, you still wind up on page 1, despite the change in the URL.

The site in question can be found [here](http://www.morepositive.com/category/gallery/).

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

ty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set [`paged`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters) or an [`offset`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Offset_Parameter) in your query, otherwise you're always fetching the same 48 posts.

```
$page = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
$args = array(
 'paged' => $page,
 'posts_per_page' => '48',
 'cat' => '4',
 'meta_query' => array(
     array(
        'key' => 'Country',
        'value' => $country_search_array,
        'compare' => 'IN'
     )
  )
);
$gallery_query = new WP_Query( $args );?>
```

Comment: That's still not working. Am I formatting the query incorrectly?

Comment: I figured it out: `$page = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;` needs to be `$page = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;`. Thanks so much, Milo!